# Determine if the file is under revision control before starting git-gutter

Tags: git, emacs

I want to speed up the emacs startup time. I've noticed that half of the time, `git-gutter+` is consuming this time for loading a long list of dependencies. Is it possible to delay loading the git-gutter stuf until I open up a file which is under revision control? Is have also `magit` installed, is there some hook or something else I can trigger if emacs/magit detect that a file is under revision control?

**EDIT**: Here are the dependency tree for git-gutter:

```
├─[git-gutter-fringe+ require 2ms]
│ ├─[fringe-helper require 2ms]
│ ╰─[git-gutter+ require 8ms]
│   ├─[warnings require 5ms]
│   ├─[git-commit-mode require 27ms]
│   │ ╰─[server require 9ms]
│   ├─[log-edit require 12ms]
│   │ ├─[pcvs-util require 6ms]
│   │ ╰─[add-log require 26ms]
│   ╰─[tramp require 38ms]
│     ╰─[tramp-compat require 5ms]
│       ├─[auth-source require 25ms]
│       │ ├─[eieio require 24ms]
│       │ │ ╰─[bytecomp require 32ms]
│       │ │   ╰─[cconv require 4ms]
│       │ ├─[gnus-util require 25ms]
│       │ ╰─[mm-util require 18ms]
│       │   ╰─[mail-prsvr require 3ms]
│       ├─[password-cache require 3ms]
│       ├─[tramp-loaddefs require 32ms]
│       │ ╰─[gv require 5ms]
│       ├─[shell require 6ms]
│       │ ├─[pcomplete require 6ms]
│       │ ╰─[comint require 27ms]
│       │   ├─[ansi-color require 4ms]
│       │   ╰─[ring require 4ms]
│       ╰─[format-spec require 3ms]
```

Comment: Do you use `emacsclient`?

Comment: Are you sure that Git Gitter slows down Emacs?  The list of `require`s in `git-gutter+.el` doesn't seem to be that long.

Comment: I used `benchmark-init` for measurement and half of the time (500ms) are used by git-gutter. I am also aware of emacsclient and the server mode. I've added the dependency tree for git-gutter.

Comment: Sorry to be off-topic, but a half-second at start-up is pretty minimal, provided you use Emacs in an emacsy sort of way (open once and leave it open all the time; use the server and `emacsclient`) and not in a Vim sort of way (open and close it repeatedly by task).